# How to make string act like double

Tags: java, string, parsing, double, joptionpane

I believe I am correct by using Double.parseDouble, but I keep getting an error. What is the problem with the code? The lines where I keep receiving errors have asterisk around them.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Interest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub


//Enter Annual Interest Rate
String annualInterestRate1;
Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 1st annual interest rate");

//Obtain Monthly Interest Rate
double monthlyInterestRate1;
**monthlyInterestRate1= annualInterestRate1 / 12;**


//Enter the Savings Amount
String savingsAmount1;
Double.parseDouble(savingsAmount1);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your 1st savings amount") ;

double endingBalance=0;



//Display Results
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adekunle Akinmola");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ");

//Calculate Payment
for(int i =0; i<=5;i++){
    **endingBalance = savingsAmount1 * (1+ monthlyInterestRate1);**
    System.out.println("$"+ endingBalance);
}

}}
```

Comment: what errors are you having?

Comment: The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: Ok, now look carefully at your code, you did parse the double from string. But you didn't use the returned value.

Comment: you never assign `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("");` return  values .

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
String annualInterestRate1;
Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 1st annual interest rate");
```

You call the right methods, but you discard the result.  Also you attempt to parse the input stream, before you have read it. I suggest you try.

```
String annualInterestRate1Str = 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 1st annual interest rate");
double annualInterestRate1 = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1Str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide a String by an integer.

Try this:

```
String annualInterestRate1 = "24";
double dblAnnualInterestRate1 = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1);

//Obtain Monthly Interest Rate
double monthlyInterestRate1 = dblAnnualInterestRate1 / 12;
```

Comment: That's why I attempted the to parse the string so that it could act as a double in the equation!

Comment: The problem is not _how_ you parsed the String, the problem is that the result of `Double.parseDouble` was never assigned to a variable. So it is lost. You should read more about the scope of variables and parameters. In your code `Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1)` does not affect annualInterestRate1. So you have to assign the _result_ of the operation to `annualInterestRate1`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
String annualInterestRate1;/ this line you need to save the value for the string and then use that.
Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1); // this line you need to save the value for the double and then use that.
```

What you want to do is

```
//Enter Annual Interest Rate
String annualInterestRate1;
annualInterestRate1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 1st annual interest rate");
double annualInterestRate1d = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1);

//Obtain Monthly Interest Rate
double monthlyInterestRate1;
monthlyInterestRate1= annualInterestRate1d / 12;
```

EDIT :

```
String savingsAmount1;
Double.parseDouble(savingsAmount1);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your 1st savings amount") ;
```

Needs to be changed to

```
String savingsAmount=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your 1st savings amount") ;
double savingsAmount1 = Double.parseDouble(savingsAmount);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, but it hasn't changed the error on the loop:     for(int i =0; i<=5;i++){
    **endingBalance = savingsAmount1 * (1+ monthlyInterestRate1);**
    System.out.println("$"+ endingBalance);
}

Comment: Same thing you need to do with savingsAmount1

Answer (score 0):

What do you think these 3 lines do?

```
String annualInterestRate1;
Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRate1);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 1st annual interest rate");
```

The first line *declares* a variable, but doesn't assign a value to it.

The second line will fail to compile, because `annualInterestRate1` hasn't been "definitely assigned".
Calling `parseDouble` without using the return value is meaningless (unless you only did it to see if the parameter was a valid `double` value, which you're not).

The third line will show a dialog to the user, asking for input, but since you're not using the return value, whatever the user types is discarded.

Maybe you should read up on assignment operators: [Assignment Statements in Java](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/assignment-statements-in-java.html)

Comment: Sorry I am very new to programming, so I am struggling on some of the small things like this

Comment: @KunleAkinmola It's ok. That's why I explained what the lines actually do, so you can learn from it. The other answers show how to fix it, but doesn't really describe what you did wrong.